# Precise flow control in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, monads, continuations

**The Idea**

Hello! I'm trying to implement in Haskell an image processing library based on dataflow ideology. I've got a problem connected to how I want to handle the flow of control.

The main idea is to introduce a `time`. The `time` is a `Float`, which could be accessed anywhere in the code (you can think of it like about State monad, but a little funnier). The funny thing about it, is that we can use `timeShift` operation on results, affecting the time corresponding operations would see.

An example would be best to explain this situation. Lets use following dataflow diagram:

```
--               timeShift(*2) --
--              /                 \
-- readImage --                    addImages -> out
--              \                 /
--                blur ----------
```

and its **pseudocode** (which deos not typecheck - its not important if we use do or let notation here, the idea should be clear):

```
test = do
    f      <- frame
    a      <- readImage $ "test" + show f + ".jpg"
    aBlur  <- blur a
    a'     <- a.timeShift(*2)
    out    <- addImage aBlur a'

main = print =<< runStateT test 5
```

The `5` is the `time` we want to run the `test` function with. The `timeShift` function affects all the operations on the left of it (in the dataflow diagram) - in this case the function `readImage` would be run twice - for both branches - the lower one would use frame `5` and the upper one frame `5*2 = 10`.

**The problem**

I'm providing here a very simple implementation, that works great, but has some caveats I want to solve. The problem is, that I want to keep the order of all IO operations. Look at the bottom for example, which will clarify what I mean.

**Sample implementation**

Below is a sample implementation of the algorithm and a code, which constructs following dataflow graph:

```
-- A --- blur --- timeShift(*2) --
--                                \
--                                 addImages -> out
--                                /
-- B --- blur --------------------
```

the code:

```
import Control.Monad.State

-- for simplicity, lets assume an Image is just a String
type Image = String

imagesStr = ["a0","b1","c2","d3","e4","f5","g6","h7","i8","j9","k10","l11","m12","n13","o14","p15","q16","r17","s18","t19","u20","v21","w22","x23","y24","z25"]
images = "abcdefghjiklmnoprstuwxyz"

--------------------------------
-- Ordinary Image processing functions

blurImg' :: Image -> Image
blurImg' img = "(blur " ++ img ++ ")"

addImage' :: Image -> Image -> Image
addImage' img1 img2 = "(add " ++ img1 ++ " " ++ img2 ++ ")"

--------------------------------
-- Functions processing Images in States

readImage1 :: StateT Int IO Image
readImage1 = do
    t <- get
    liftIO . putStrLn $ "[1] reading image with time: " ++ show t
    return $ imagesStr !! t

readImage2 :: StateT Int IO Image
readImage2 = do
    t <- get
    liftIO . putStrLn $ "[2] reading image with time: " ++ show t
    return $ imagesStr !! t

blurImg :: StateT Int IO Image -> StateT Int IO Image
blurImg img = do
    i <- img
    liftIO $ putStrLn "blurring"
    return $ blurImg' i

addImage :: StateT Int IO Image -> StateT Int IO Image -> StateT Int IO Image
addImage img1 img2 = do
    i1 <- img1
    i2 <- img2
    liftIO $ putStrLn "adding images"
    return $ addImage' i1 i2


timeShift :: StateT Int IO Image -> (Int -> Int) -> StateT Int IO Image
timeShift img f = do
    t <- get
    put (f t)
    i <- img
    put t
    return i

test = out where
    i1   = readImage1
    j1   = readImage2

    i2   = blurImg i1
    j2   = blurImg j1

    i3   = timeShift i2 (*2)
    out  = addImage i3 j2


main = do
    print =<< runStateT test 5
    print "end"
```

The output is:

```
[1] reading image with time: 10
blurring
[2] reading image with time: 5
blurring
adding images
("(add (blur k10) (blur f5))",5)
"end"
```

and should be:

```
[1] reading image with time: 10
[2] reading image with time: 5
blurring
blurring
adding images
("(add (blur k10) (blur f5))",5)
"end"
```

**Please note** that the correct output is `("(add (blur k10) (blur f5))",5)` - which means, that we added image `k10` to `f5` - from respectively 10th and 5th frame.

**Further requirements**
I'm looking for a solution, which would allow users to write simple code (like in `test` function - it could of course be in a Monad), but I do not want them to handle the time-shifting logic by hand.

**Conclusions**

The only difference is the order of IO actions execution. I would love to preserve the order of the IO actions just like they are written in the `test` function. I was trying to implement the idea using `Countinuations`, `Arrows` and some funny states, but without success.

Comment: I believe your question is underspecified. What about `a <- readImage "test.jpg"; a' <- timeShift (*(width a)); addImage a a'` or some other case where you have dependencies between the operations? Is `Applicative` structure enough for your purposes, instead of `Monad`?

Comment: To be more precise, `a <- readImage "1"; b <- readImage "2"; c <- blur a; c <- timeShift b (*(mod (hash blur) 10))`, in this scenario it's just not possible to load the `c` image before the `blur` operation

Comment: This resembles a lot [Functional Reactive Programming](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_Reactive_Programming).

Comment: Why do you care which order operations occur in which have no data dependencies between them?

Comment: My friend created this [Haskell image processing library](https://github.com/jcollard/unm-hip) that might prove useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Dataflow and functional reactive programming libraries in Haskell are usually written in terms of `Applicative` or `Arrow`. These are abstractions for computations that are less general than `Monad`s - the `Applicative` and `Arrow` typeclasses do not expose a way for the structure of computations to depend on the results of other computations. As a result, libraries exposing only these typeclasses can reason about the structure of computations in the library independently of performing those computations. We will solve your problem in terms of the `Applicative` typeclass

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    -- | Lift a value.
    pure :: a -> f a    
    -- | Sequential application.
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

`Applicative` allows a library user to make new computations with `pure`, operate on existing computations with `fmap` (from `Functor`) and compose computations together with `<*>`, using the result of one computation as an input for another. It does not allow a library user to make a computation that makes another computation and then use the result of that computation directly; there's no way a user can write `join :: f (f a) -> f a`. This restriction will keep our library from running into the [problem I described in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25733133/414413).

#### Transformers, free, and the ApT transformer

Your example problem is quite involved, so we are going to pull out a bunch of high level Haskell tricks, and make a few new ones of our own. The first two tricks we are going to pull out are [transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers) and [free](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) data types. Transformers are types that take types with a kind like that of `Functor`s, `Applicative`s or `Monad`s and produce new types with the same kind.

Transformers typically look like the following `Double` example. `Double` can take any `Functor` or `Applicative` or `Monad` and make a version of it that always holds two values instead of one

```
newtype Double f a = Double {runDouble :: f (a, a)}
```

Free data types are transformers that do two things. First, given some simpler property of the underlying type the gain new exciting properties for the transformed type. The `Free` `Monad` provides a `Monad` given any `Functor`, and the free `Applicative`, `Ap`, makes an `Applicative` out of any `Functor`. The other thing "free" types do is they ["free" the implementation of the interpreter as much as possible](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html). Here are the types for the free `Applicative`, `Ap`, the free `Monad`, `Free`, and the free monad transfomer, `FreeT`. The free monad transformer provides a monad transformer for "free" given a `Functor`

```
-- Free Applicative
data Ap f a where
    Pure :: a -> Ap f a
    Ap   :: f a -> Ap f (a -> b) -> Ap f b

-- Base functor of the free monad transformer
data FreeF f a b
    = Pure a    
    | Free (f b)    

-- Free monad transformer
newtype FreeT f m a = FreeT {runFreeT :: m (FreeF f a (FreeT f m a)}

-- The free monad is the free monad transformer applied to the Identity monad
type Free f = FreeT f Identity
```

Here's a sketch of our goal - we want to provide an `Applicative` interface for combining computations, which, at the bottom, allows `Monad`ic computations. We want to "free" the interpreter as much as possible so that it can hopefully reorder computations. To do this, we will be combining both the free `Applicative` and the free monad transformer.

We want an `Applicative` interface, and the easiest one to make is the one we can get for "free", which aligns nicely with out goal of "freeing the interpeter" as much as possible. This suggests our type  is going to look like

```
Ap f a
```

for some `Functor` `f` and any `a`. We'd like the underlying computation to be over some `Monad`, and `Monad`s are functors, but we'd like to "free" the interpreter as much as posssible. We'll grab the free monad transformer as the underlying functor for `Ap`, giving us

```
Ap (FreeT f m) a
```

for some `Functor` `f`, some `Monad` `m`, and any `a`. We know the `Monad` `m` is probably going to be `IO`, but we'll leave our code as generic as possible. We just need to provide the `Functor` for `FreeT`. All `Applicatives` are `Functors`, so `Ap` itself could be used for `f`, we'd write something like

```
type ApT m a = Ap (FreeT (ApT m) m) a
```

This gives the compiler fits, so instead we'll mover the `Ap` inside and define

```
newtype ApT m a = ApT {unApT :: FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a}
```

We'll derive some instances for this and discuss its real motivation after an interlude.

#### Interlude

To run all of this code, you'll need the following. The `Map` and `Control.Concurrent` are only needed for sharing computations, more on that much later.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Applicative

import Control.Applicative.Free hiding (Pure)
import qualified Control.Applicative.Free as Ap (Ap(Pure))
import Control.Monad.Trans.Free

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Concurrent
```

#### Stuffing it

I mislead you in the previous section, and pretended to discover `ApT` from resoning about the problem. I actually discovered `ApT` by trying anything and everything to try to stuff `Monad`ic computations into an `Applicative` and be able to control their order when it came out. For a long time, I was trying to solve how to implement `mapApM` (below) in order to write `flipImage` (my replacement for your `blur`). Here's the `ApT` `Monad` transformer in all its glory. It's intended to be used as the `Functor` for an `Ap`, and, by using `Ap` as its own `Functor` for `FreeT`, can magically stuff values into an `Applicative` that shouldn't seem possible.

```
newtype ApT m a = ApT {unApT :: FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a}
     deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)
```

It could derive even more instances from `FreeT`, these are just the ones we need. It can't derive `MonadTrans`, but we can do that ourselves:

```
instance MonadTrans ApT where
    lift = ApT . lift

runApT :: ApT m a -> m (FreeF (Ap (ApT m)) a (FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a))
runApT = runFreeT . unApT
```

The real beauty of `ApT` is we can write some seemingly impossible code like

```
stuffM :: (Functor m, Monad m) => m (ApT m a) -> ApT m a
stuffMAp :: (Functor m, Monad m) => m (ApT m a) -> Ap (ApT m) a
```

The `m` on the outside disappeares, even into `Ap` that's merely `Applicative`.

This works because of the following cycle of functions, each of which can stuff the output from the function above it into the input of the function below it. The first function starts with an `ApT m a`, and the last one ends with one. (These definitions aren't part of the program)

```
liftAp' :: ApT m a ->
           Ap (ApT m) a
liftAp' = liftAp

fmapReturn :: (Monad m) =>
               Ap (ApT m) a ->
               Ap (ApT m) (FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a)
fmapReturn = fmap return

free' :: Ap (ApT m) (FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a) ->
         FreeF (Ap (ApT m)) a (FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a)
free' = Free

pure' :: a ->
         FreeF (Ap (ApT m)) a (FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a)
pure' = Pure

return' :: (Monad m) =>
           FreeF (Ap (ApT m)) a (FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a) ->
           m (FreeF (Ap (ApT m)) a (FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a))
return' = return

freeT :: m (FreeF (Ap (ApT m)) a (FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a)) ->
         FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a
freeT = FreeT

apT :: FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a ->
       ApT m a
apT = ApT
```

This lets us write

```
-- Get rid of an Ap by stuffing it into an ApT.
stuffAp :: (Monad m) => Ap (ApT m) a -> ApT m a
stuffAp = ApT . FreeT . return . Free . fmap return

-- Stuff ApT into Free
stuffApTFree :: (Monad m) => ApT m a -> FreeF (Ap (ApT m)) a (FreeT (Ap (ApT m)) m a)
stuffApTFree = Free . fmap return . liftAp

-- Get rid of an m by stuffing it into an ApT
stuffM :: (Functor m, Monad m) => m (ApT m a) -> ApT m a
stuffM = ApT . FreeT . fmap stuffApTFree

-- Get rid of an m by stuffing it into an Ap
stuffMAp :: (Functor m, Monad m) => m (ApT m a) -> Ap (ApT m) a
stuffMAp = liftAp . stuffM
```

And some utility functions for working on a transformer stack

```
mapFreeT :: (Functor f, Functor m, Monad m) => (m a -> m b) -> FreeT f m a -> FreeT f m b
mapFreeT f fa = do
    a <- fa
    FreeT . fmap Pure . f . return $ a

mapApT :: (Functor m, Monad m) => (m a -> m b) -> ApT m a -> ApT m b
mapApT f = ApT . mapFreeT f . unApT

mapApM :: (Functor m, Monad m) => (m a -> m b) -> Ap (ApT m) a -> Ap (ApT m) b
mapApM f = liftAp . mapApT f . stuffAp
```

We'd like to start writing our example image processors, but first we need to take another diversion to address a hard requirement.

#### A hard requirement - input sharing

Your first example shows

```
--               timeShift(*2) --
--              /                 \
-- readImage --                    addImages -> out
--              \                 /
--                blur ----------
```

implying that the result of `readImage` should be shared between `blur` and `timeShift(*2)`. I take this to mean that the results of `readImage` should only be computed once for each time.

`Applicative` isn't powerful enough to capture this. We'll make a new typeclass to represent computations whose output can be divided into multiple identical streams.

```
-- The class of things where input can be shared and divided among multiple parts
class Applicative f => Divisible f where
    (<\>) :: (f a -> f b) -> f a -> f b
```

We'll make a transformer that adds this capability to existing `Applicative`s

```
-- A transformer that adds input sharing
data LetT f a where
    NoLet :: f a -> LetT f a
    Let   :: LetT f b -> (LetT f b -> LetT f a) -> LetT f a
```

And provide some utility functions and instances for it

```
-- A transformer that adds input sharing
data LetT f a where
    NoLet :: f a -> LetT f a
    Let   :: LetT f b -> (LetT f b -> LetT f a) -> LetT f a

liftLetT :: f a -> LetT f a
liftLetT = NoLet

mapLetT :: (f a -> f b) -> LetT f a -> LetT f b
mapLetT f = go
    where
        go (NoLet a) = NoLet (f a)
        go (Let b g) = Let b (go . g)

instance (Applicative f) => Functor (LetT f) where
    fmap f = mapLetT (fmap f)

-- I haven't checked that these obey the Applicative laws.
instance (Applicative f) => Applicative (LetT f) where
    pure = NoLet . pure
    NoLet f <*> a = mapLetT (f <*>) a
    Let c h <*> a = Let c ((<*> a) . h)   

instance (Applicative f) => Divisible (LetT f) where
    (<\>) = flip Let
```

#### Image processors

With all of our transformers in place, we can start writing our image processors. At the bottom of our stack we have our `ApT` from an earlier section

```
Ap (ApT IO)
```

The computations need to be able to read the time from the environment, so we'll add a `ReaderT` for that

```
ReaderT Int (Ap (ApT IO))
```

Finally, we'd like to be able to share computations, so we'll add out `LetT` transformer on top, giving the entire type `IP` for our image processors

```
type Image = String
type IP = LetT (ReaderT Int (Ap (ApT IO)))
```

We'll read images from `IO`. `getLine` makes fun interactive examples.

```
readImage :: Int -> IP Image
readImage n = liftLetT $ ReaderT (\t -> liftAp . liftIO $ do
    putStrLn $  "[" ++ show n ++ "] reading image for time: " ++ show t
    --getLine
    return $ "|image [" ++ show n ++ "] for time: " ++ show t ++ "|"
    )
```

We can shift the time of inputs

```
timeShift :: (Int -> Int) -> IP a -> IP a
timeShift f = mapLetT shift
    where
        shift (ReaderT g) = ReaderT (g . f)
```

Add multiple images together

```
addImages :: Applicative f => [f Image] -> f Image
addImages = foldl (liftA2 (++)) (pure [])
```

And flip images pretending to use some library that's stuck in `IO`. I couldn't figure out how to `blur` a string...

```
inIO :: (IO a -> IO b) -> IP a -> IP b
inIO = mapLetT . mapReaderT . mapApM        

flipImage :: IP [a] -> IP [a]
flipImage = inIO flip'
    where
        flip' ma = do
            a <- ma
            putStrLn "flipping"
            return . reverse $ a
```

#### Interpreting LetT

Our `LetT` for sharing results is at the top of our transformer stack. We'll need to interpret it to get at the computations underneath it. To interpret `LetT` we will need a way to share results in `IO`, which `memoize` provides, and an interpeter that removes the `LetT` transformer from the top of the stack.

To share computations we need to store them somewhere, this `memoize`s an `IO` computation in `IO`, making sure it happens only once even across multiple threads.

```
memoize :: (Ord k) => (k -> IO a) -> IO (k -> IO a)
memoize definition = do
    cache <- newMVar Map.empty
    let populateCache k map = do
        case Map.lookup k map of
            Just a -> return (map, a)
            Nothing -> do
                a <- definition k
                return (Map.insert k a map, a)        
    let fromCache k = do
        map <- readMVar cache
        case Map.lookup k map of
            Just a -> return a
            Nothing -> modifyMVar cache (populateCache k)
    return fromCache
```

In order to interpret a `Let`, we need an evaluator for the underlying `ApT IO` to incorporate into the definitions for the `Let` bindings. Since the result of computations depends on the environment read from the `ReaderT`, we will incorporate dealing with the `ReaderT` into this step. A more sophisticated approach would use transformer classes, but transformer classes for `Applicative` is a topic for a different question.

```
compileIP :: (forall x. ApT IO x -> IO x) ->  IP a -> IO (Int -> ApT IO a)
compileIP eval (NoLet (ReaderT f)) = return (stuffAp . f)
compileIP eval (Let b lf) = do
            cb <- compileIP eval b
            mb <- memoize (eval . cb)
            compileIP eval . lf . NoLet $ ReaderT (liftAp . lift . mb)
```

#### Interpreting ApT

Our interpreter uses the following `State` to avoid needing to peek inside `AsT`, `FreeT`, and `FreeF` all the time.

```
data State m a where
    InPure :: a -> State m a
    InAp :: State m b -> State m (b -> State m a) -> State m a
    InM :: m a -> State m a

instance Functor m => Functor (State m) where
    fmap f (InPure a) = InPure (f a)
    fmap f (InAp b sa) = InAp b (fmap (fmap (fmap f)) sa)
    fmap f (InM  m)  = InM  (fmap f m)
```

Interpereting `Ap` is harder than it looks. The goal is to take data that's in `Ap.Pure` and put it in `InPure` and data that's in `Ap` and put it in `InAp`. `interpretAp` actually needs to call itself with a larger type each time it goes into a deeper `Ap`; the function keeps picking up another argument. The first argument `t` provides a way to simplify these otherwise exploding types.

```
interpretAp :: (Functor m) => (a -> State m b) -> Ap m a -> State m b
interpretAp t (Ap.Pure a) = t a
interpretAp t (Ap mb ap) = InAp sb sf
    where
        sb = InM mb
        sf = interpretAp (InPure . (t .)) $ ap
```

`interperetApT` gets data out of `ApT`, `FreeT`, and `FreeF` and into `State m`

```
interpretApT :: (Functor m, Monad m) => ApT m a -> m (State (ApT m) a)
interpretApT = (fmap inAp) . runApT
    where
        inAp (Pure a) = InPure a
        inAp (Free ap) = interpretAp (InM . ApT) $ ap
```

With these simple interpreting pieces we can make strategies for interpreting results. Each strategy is a function from the interpreter's `State` to a new `State`, with possible side effect happening on the way. The order the strategy chooses to execute side effects in determines the order of the side effects. We'll make two example strategies.

The first strategy performs only one step on everything that's ready to be computed, and combines results when they are ready. This is probably the strategy that you want.

```
stepFB :: (Functor m, Monad m) => State (ApT m) a -> m (State (ApT m) a)
stepFB (InM ma)   = interpretApT ma
stepFB (InPure a) = return (InPure a)
stepFB (InAp b f) = do
    sf <- stepFB f
    sb <- stepFB b
    case (sf, sb) of
        (InPure f, InPure b) -> return (f b)
        otherwise            -> return (InAp sb sf)
```

This other strategy performs all the calculations as soon as it knows about them. It performs them all in a single pass.

```
allFB :: (Functor m, Monad m) => State (ApT m) a -> m (State (ApT m) a)
allFB (InM ma) = interpretApT ma
allFB (InPure a) = return (InPure a)
allFB (InAp b f) = do
    sf <- allFB f
    sb <- allFB b
    case (sf, sb) of
        (InPure f, InPure b) -> return (f b)
        otherwise            -> allFB (InAp sb sf)
```

Many, many other strategies are possible.

We can evaluate a strategy by running it until it produces a single result.

```
untilPure :: (Monad m) => ((State f a) -> m (State f a)) -> State f a -> m a
untilPure s = go
    where
        go state =
            case state of
                (InPure a) -> return a
                otherwise  -> s state >>= go
```

#### Executing the intepreter

To execute the interpreter, we need some example data. Here are a few interesting examples.

```
example1  = (\i -> addImages [timeShift (*2) i, flipImage i]) <\> readImage 1
example1' = (\i -> addImages [timeShift (*2) i, flipImage i, flipImage . timeShift (*2) $ i]) <\> readImage 1
example1'' = (\i -> readImage 2) <\> readImage 1
example2 = addImages [timeShift (*2) . flipImage $ readImage 1, flipImage $ readImage 2]
```

The `LetT` interpreter needs to know what evaluator to use for bound values, so we'll define our evaluator only once. A single `interpretApT` kicks off the evaluation by finding the initial `State` of the interpreter.

```
evaluator :: ApT IO x -> IO x
evaluator = (>>= untilPure stepFB) . interpretApT
```

We'll compile `example2`, which is essentially your example, and run it for time 5.

```
main = do
    f <- compileIP evaluator example2
    a <- evaluator . f $ 5
    print a
```

Which produces almost the desired result, with all reads happening before any flips.

```
[2] reading image for time: 5
[1] reading image for time: 10
flipping
flipping
"|01 :emit rof ]1[ egami||5 :emit rof ]2[ egami|"
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Monad` can not reorder the component steps that make up `img1` and `img2` in

```
addImage :: (Monad m) => m [i] -> m [i] -> m [i]
addImage img1 img2 = do
    i1 <- img1
    i2 <- img2
    return $ i1 ++ i2
```

if there exists any `m [i]` whose result depends on a side effect. Any `MonadIO m` has an `m [i]` whose result depends on a side effect, therefore you cannot reorder the component steps of `img1` and `img2`.

The above desugars to

```
addImage :: (Monad m) => m [i] -> m [i] -> m [i]
addImage img1 img2 =
    img1 >>=
        (\i1 ->
            img2 >>=
                (\i2 ->
                    return (i1 ++ i2)
                )
        )
```

Let's focus on the first `>>=` (remembering that `(>>=) :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`). Specialized for our type, this is `(>>=) :: m [i] -> ([i] -> m [i]) -> m [i]`. If we are going to implement it, we'd have to write something like

```
(img1 :: m [i]) >>= (f :: [i] -> m [i]) = ...
```

In order to do anything with `f`, we need to pass it an `[i]`. The only correct `[i]` we have is stuck inside `img1 :: m [i]`. We need the result of `img1` to do anything with `f`. There are now two possibilities. We either **can** or **can not** determine the result of `img1` without executing its side effects. We will examine both cases, starting with when we can not.

#### can not

When we can not determine the result of `img1` without executing its side effects, we have only one choice - we must execute `img1` and all of its side effects. We now have an `[i]`, but all of `img1`s side effects have already been executed. There's no way we can execute any of the side effects from `img2` before some of the side effects of `img1` because the side effects of `img1` have already happened.

#### can

If we can determine the result of `img1` without executing its side effects, we're in luck. We find the result of `img1` and pass that to `f`, getting a new `m [i]` holding the result we want. We can now examine the side effects of both `img1` and the new `m [i]` and reorder them (although there's a huge caveat here about the associative law for `>>=`).

#### the problem at hand

As this applies to our case, for any `MonadIO`, there exists the following, whose result  can not be determined without executing its side effects, placing us firmly in the **can not** case where we can not re-order side effects.

```
counterExample :: (MonadIO m) => m String
counterExample = liftIO getLine
```

There are also many other counter examples, such as anything like `readImage1` or `readImage2` that must actually read the image from `IO`.