# Are applicative transformers really superfluous?

Tags: haskell, stream, typeclass

There is a lot of talk about `Applicative` *not* needing its own transformer class, like this:

```
class AppTrans t where
    liftA :: Applicative f => f a -> t f a
```

But I can define applicative transformers that don't seem to be compositions of applicatives! For example *sideeffectful streams*:

```
data MStream f a = MStream (f (a, MStream f a))
```

Lifting just performs the side effect at every step:

```
instance AppTrans MStream where
    liftA action = MStream $ (,) <$> action <*> pure (liftA action)
```

And if `f` is an applicative, then `MStream f` is as well:

```
instance Functor f => Functor (MStream f) where
    fmap fun (MStream stream) = MStream $ (\(a, as) -> (fun a, fmap fun as)) <$> stream

instance Applicative f => Applicative (MStream f) where
    pure = liftA . pure
    MStream fstream <*> MStream astream = MStream
        $ (\(f, fs) (a, as) -> (f a, fs <*> as)) <$> fstream <*> astream
```

I know that for any practical purposes, `f` should be a monad:

```
joinS :: Monad m => MStream m a -> m [a]
joinS (MStream stream) = do
    (a, as) <- stream
    aslist <- joinS as
    return $ a : aslist
```

But while there is a `Monad` instance for `MStream m`, it's inefficient. (Or even incorrect?) The `Applicative` instance is actually useful!

Now note that usual streams arise as special cases for the identity functor:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity
type Stream a = MStream Identity a
```

But the composition of `Stream` and `f` is not `MStream f`! Rather, `Compose Stream f a` is isomorphic to `Stream (f a)`.

*I'd like to know whether `MStream` is a composition of any two applicatives.*

Edit:

I'd like to offer a category theoretic viewpoint. A transformer is a "nice" endofunctor `t` on the category `C` of applicative functors (i.e. lax monoidal functors with strength), together with a natural transformation `liftA` from the identity on `C` to `t`. The more general question is now what useful transformers exist that are not of the form "compose with `g`" (where `g` is an applicative). My claim is that `MStream` is one of them.

Comment: Take any monad transformer that does not work by simple composition (StateT, ListT, ContT, etc.). This will give you an example of a nontrivial applicative transformer as well, since each monad is automatically an applicative functor.

Comment: My comment was too quick. In a lot of cases, what I said doesn't work. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673525/is-it-possible-to-implement-applicative-m-applicative-statet-s-m

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Great question! I believe there are two different parts of this question:

1. **Composing** existing applicatives or monads into more complex ones.
2. **Constructing all** applicatives/monads from some given starting set.

Ad 1.: **Monad transformers are essential for combining monads.** Monads [don't compose directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13034229/1333025). It seems that there needs to be an extra bit of information provided by monad transformers that tells how each monad can be composed with other monads (but it could be this information is already somehow present, see [Is there a monad that doesn't have a corresponding monad transformer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24515876/1333025)).

On the other hand, **applicatives compose directly**, see [Data.Functor.Compose](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html). This is why don't need applicative transformers for composition. They're also closed under [product](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html) (but not [coproduct](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Sum.html)).

For example, having [infinite streams](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Stream-0.4.7.2/docs/Data-Stream.html) `data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)` and another applicative `g`, both `Stream (g a)` and `g (Stream a)` are applicatives.

But even though `Stream` is also a monad (`join` takes the diagonal of a 2-dimensional stream), its composition with another monad `m` won't be, neither `Stream (m a)` nor `m (Stream a)` will always be a monad.

Furthermore as we can see, they're both different from your `MStream g` (which is very close to [`ListT` done right](https://wiki.haskell.org/ListT_done_right)), therefore:

Ad 2.: **Can all applicatives be constructed from some given set of primitives?** Apparently not. One problem is constructing sum data types: If `f` and `g` are applicatives, `Either (f a) (g a)` won't be, as we don't know how to compose `Right h <*> Left x`.

Another construction primitive is taking a fixed point, as in your `MStream`  example. Here we might attempt to generalize the construction by defining something like

```
newtype Fix1 f a = Fix1 { unFix1 :: f (Fix1 f) a }

instance (Functor (f (Fix1 f))) => Functor (Fix1 f) where
    fmap f (Fix1 a) = Fix1 (fmap f a)

instance (Applicative (f (Fix1 f))) => Applicative (Fix1 f) where
    pure k = Fix1 (pure k)
    (Fix1 f) <*> (Fix1 x) = Fix1 (f <*> x)
```

(which requires not-so-nice `UndecidableInstances`) and then

```
data MStream' f g a = MStream (f (a, g a))

type MStream f = Fix1 (MStream' f)
```